# How can I recreate a codepen locally on my computer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, codepen

So I found a nice website on CodePen and I want to copy/paste it local so I can play with it a bit. I have created all 3 files ( html, css, javascript ) in the same folder and I linked them in the html file.
In the local folder I have : index.html + stylesheet.css + Javass.js.

I have linked them in  respectively  like this:

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
     <script src="Javass.js"></script>
```

I think the css file is showing but not the js one. Can you help me?

Edit: https://codepen.io/TurkAysenur/pen/gORaboY (this is the codepen)

Comment: Please show your index.html file + share your project folder/file structure to get a better answer from people. The question don't clarify where you have made a mistake

Comment: How many `<body></body>` do you have?

Comment: I'm sure if you share the link to the CodePen, that someone will show you how to modify the HTML properly. CodePen allows implicit embedding of scripts and stylesheets via configuration, so there might be some unexpected modifications that you need to make.

Comment: I opened the CodePen, clicked the "export" button in the lower right, and selected Export.zip.  The archive contained a dist folder with all the required files ready to run, i.e., full html page.   Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Yogi, thank you, that is indeed easier that what I was trying to do and it worked for me as well, now seeing the solution, the question seems a bit "dumb". Thank you all again!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell like this.
Though here are the common things:

1. Copy code pen's html into the body html element (don't replace the whole code)
2. Make sure JS runs after page loaded ( `window.onload=()=>{...}` ) or any other solution for that.

Edit: according to [Yogi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/943435/yogi) there is an export button. This could be the simplest solution for you